# Querying a table with an array of json objects in RedbeanPHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, redbean

I'm having trouble working in Redbean PHP with querying a table with an array of json objects in a single field, and producing a report on it.

I want to get a report with subtotals of all staff with notes by the category. I know this should be easy/obvious but I'm just not getting it properly.

I have a database, with:

```
table clients
with columns:(int) client_id, (string) client_name, (array of json) notes
notes is an array of json with 
(int) note_id, (int) note_category_id, (int) staff_id, (string) description, (memo) content, (date) note_date

table staff with columns (int) sid, (string) sname

table categories with columns (int) cat_id, (string) cat_name
```

So in pseudocode (since I'm still trying to figure this all out)
I need to run a query like: (with parameters in brackets)

```
R::getAll('Select * from Join (staff, categories, clients) 
On (staff.sid=clients.services.staff_id, categories.cat_id=clients.services.note_category_id)
Where (clients.services.note_date Between [startdate] and [enddate], 
  categories.cat_name IN [chosencateg], staff.sname IN [pickednames])
Orderby sname Asc, cat_name Asc, note_date Desc ');
```

report output format:

```
Filters used: [picked filter choices if any]
-----------
[sname]
--  note category: [cat_name] 1
        [note_date] 1   [description] 1 [content] 1
        [note_date] 2   [description] 2 [content] 2
    note category 1 subtotal
--  note category: [cat_name] 2
        [note_date] 3   [description] 3 [content] 3
        [note_date] 4   [description] 4 [content] 4
    note category 2 subtotal
staff subtotal
[sname] 2 ...
```

I'm asking a fairly generic one because I'll have to work with a number of similar tables, and maybe seeing a query template will help my understanding.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I STRONGLY recommend you create a separate table for the notes, with columns for the different note attributes, rather than store the notes as an array of JSON objects. You are sacrificing all the power of your relational database to keep big confusing strings with a bunch of data in them. The way it is, you will be fighting your database design forever.

Comment: This is 'legacy code'(maybe 2 yrs old, still able to contact the consultant to an extent), and they've used arrays of json objects in many areas - note fields, additional family members/contact info, questionnaires/screenings q&a, issues, address/school changes... areas you might have zero to many  or changes over time it seems like. I assumed this is hybrid SQL/NoSql maybe? don't really know enough yet

Comment: What version of redbean are you using? json data is really just a string. So - to say you're storing json inside a database column doesn't sound unusual, it's just a string. You should be able to access the string and output it to the screen just like any other string. Once you want to convert it to an array you can just use json_decode($myJsonString,true) and it should come out as an associative array.

Comment: redbean 4.3, though I should be able to upgrade if it would be better

Answer (score 0):

redbean is fantastic and - getAll is just scratching the surface and truly isn't working with redbean at all really... [Read up on it here](https://redbeanphp.com/manual3_0/index.php?p=/manual3_0/queries):

Here's a query template to get you started:

Query Template:

1)

```
R::getAll('Select * from Join (staff, categories, clients) 
On (staff.sid=clients.services.staff_id, categories.cat_id=clients.services.note_category_id)
Where (clients.services.note_date Between :startdate and :enddate, 
  categories.cat_name IN (:chosencateg), staff.sname IN (:pickednames))
Orderby sname Asc, cat_name Asc, note_date Desc ');
```

You could also simply use:

2)

```
R::getAll('Select * from Join (staff, categories, clients) 
On (staff.sid=clients.services.staff_id, categories.cat_id=clients.services.note_category_id)
Where (clients.services.note_date Between ? and ?, 
  categories.cat_name IN (?), staff.sname IN (?))
Orderby sname Asc, cat_name Asc, note_date Desc ');
```

The only difference is that query template 1 uses named parameters (so it's going to look to the array of params that you pass it to contain an associative array with parameters named in the same way as they are in the query). While template 2 requires simply an array of parameters with the indexes lined up with the order in which the ? marks appear in your query.

Anyway... the query should return an associative array of your columns representing rows. a var_dump would look something like this:

```
Array
(
[client_id] => 1,
[client_name] => "joe",
[noes] => "[
           {note_id=1
           ,note_category_id=1
           ,staff_id=1
           ,description=blah blah
           ,content=blah blah blah blah
           ,content=some content for this note
           ,note_date=12/06/2018
           }
           ]"
[sid] => 100,
[sname] => "some staff name"
[cat_id] => 100
[cat_name] => "some category name"
)
```

Notice how the notes field has just come out as a string (I know the json above is not properly formed json, I'm just trying to show an example).

I assume that what you want is to have that string converted into an array so you can work with it as if it were data and not a string. So the below should get you started with that:

Once you have it out of the database you should be able to access it like this:

```
$result = R::getAll($query,
['startdate'=> $mystartDate
,'enddate' => $myEndDate
,'chosencateg'=>$myChosenCategory
,'pickednames'=>$myPickedNames
]);
// this would output the json string to your screen
echo $result['notes'];
```

but it seems like you want to work with the json as if it were part of your data - so... you would need to decode it first.

```
// decode my notes field:
foreach(array_key($result) as $key) {
/* you are working with a multidimensional array in this loop
, use $key to access the row index. Each row index 
will contain named column indexes that are column names from the database
*/
$result[$key]['decoded_notes'] = json_decode($result[$key]['notes'],true);
}
// I now have a new column in each row index, containing 'notes'
```

as another associative array

```
// the statement below now results in an array to string conversion error:
echo $result[someIndexNumber]['decoded_notes'];
```

Comment: When attempting to use that query I get Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'clients.notes.content' in 'field list'. I'm trying to make a fiddle to show it better.  I really want it to treat the array of json as another table and be able to query on it. Openjson and Cross Apply might be what I'm looking for, or do I turn the rest of the table and the json columns into arrays/nested beans to work with in redbean?. Probably something related to NoSql database queries.

Comment: I see - this is in mysql right? maybe try json_contains() https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html. Or some other derivative of the json search functions described in that document. - It would really be good if you read up on redbean - there's a great deal of relationship management you get out of the box from that ORM.

Comment: possibilities? 1)string manipulation - though checking in a range of dates sounds slooow, 2) convert json to assoc array and array_filter and array_map in php, 3) loop through. 4) use redbean withCondition or ownSomething or some other way to add conditions?

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided I would want this in MySQL (5.7) so as to use its capabilities. To do this I used string manipulation. MySQL 8 adds json_table functions which would have been nice to have.

I converted each array of JSON notes into lines of 'INSERT INTO temptable' to convert the array list into temptable rows,
one JSON object per row, adding the client_id to each object, then 
EXECUTEing those statements.

```
SET @allnotes = (
SELECT json_arrayagg(REPLACE(`notes`,'{', CONCAT('{"id_client": ', id_client, ', ')))   /* add id_client to each note object */
FROM clients
WHERE `notes` != '' AND `notes` != '[]' );                      /* no empty note cases */
SET @allnotes = REPLACE(REPLACE(@allnotes ,'"[',''),']"','' );      /* flatten out outer array of each note */
SET @allnotes = REPLACE(REPLACE(@allnotes ,'{','("{'),'}','}")' );  /* INSERT INTO string formatting for the objects */

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS jsonTemporary;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jsonTemporary (anote json);
SET @allnotes = REPLACE(REPLACE(@allnotes,'[','INSERT INTO jsonTemporary (anote) VALUES '),']',';');

PREPARE astatement FROM @allnotes;
EXECUTE astatement;

/* totals */
SELECT concat(staff.last_name,", ",staff.first_name) AS sname,
categories.name AS cat_name,
count(anote->'$.id_client') AS cat_total,
FROM jsonTemporary
JOIN categories ON cast(anote->'$.note_category_id' as unsigned)=categories.id
JOIN clients ON clients.id_client=anote->'$.id_client'
JOIN staff ON staff.id=anote->'$.staff_id'
WHERE anote->'$.note_date' >= "2018-10-01" AND anote->'$.note_date' <= "2018-12-31"
GROUP BY sname, cat_name;

/* all notes */
SELECT concat(staff.last_name,", ",staff.first_name) AS sname,
categories.name AS cat_name,
anote->'$.note_date' AS n_date,
anote->'$.description' AS description,
anote->'$.content' AS content,
FROM jsonTemporary
JOIN categories ON cast(anote->'$.note_category_id' as unsigned)=categories.id
JOIN clients ON clients.id_client=anote->'$.id_client'
JOIN staff ON staff.id=anote->'$.staff_id'
WHERE anote->'$.note_date' >= "2018-10-01" AND anote->'$.note_date' <= "2018-12-31"
GROUP BY sname, cat_name;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS jsonTemporary;
```